# Range of duty cycle ms to drive RC servo motor and transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, servo, duty-cycle

I am using the ball and beam control system from Acrome robotics and I would like to identify the transfer function of the RC servo motor which translates motion to the system. First of all, I have asked the company for information about the model of the motor used but I have not received an answer. Is there any way to find out the milliseconds in order to put the servo at 0,90 degrees ? And if I collect the input data (ms of duty cycle) and output data (degrees), can I figure out the transfer function of the motor’s system ?

Comment: The standard is a 1ms to 2ms pulse with 1.5ms being the center. A linear relationship across this range maps the pulse width to the position between the end throws. The frequency is not too important but should be frequent enough so the motor updates it's position frequently enough to hold but not so high the motor overheats. Duty cycle is irrelevant. it is the high-time of the pulse that matters.

Comment: @DKNguyen: I was quite surprised a few years ago to discover that for "analog" servos, duty cycle **is** relevant.  Then I remembered that analog servos have a "pulse stretcher".  Apparently if your pulse-pulse time gets smaller than the stretched-pulse time, the servo goes nuts (that's a technical term -- it means it goes wonky).

Comment: This is a textbook example of lacking research effort - this kind of information is not only documented across the Internet, but RC sites are full of pictures of people putting protractor scales and pointers on servos and measuring response.

Comment: The RC servo motor is closed inside a metal box. I am not able to directly interact with it. So I am looking for some other methods in order to perform system identification. I am trying to figure out the kind of data that is appropriate for the identification.

Comment: Measure the movement of whatever part sticks out of the box.  Or take it apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most hobby servos have a rotation angle of 90° when the pulse width is varied from 1 to 2ms. The standard frame rate is 50Hz (20ms PWM period). Digital servos can often handle frame rates up to ~250Hz, but analog servos tend to misbehave (or even burn out) above 60Hz.

There is no standard rotation direction - some go clockwise with increasing pulse width and some go anticlockwise. Maximum deflection depends on the control circuit and the mechanism. Mechanical stops are usually placed at or just before 180°.

The actual angle depends on where the arm has been set on the spline. So if you set the pulse width to eg. 1.5ms (midpoint) and want a particular arm position at this point then undo the locking screw and move the arm to the closest spline position, then adjust the pulse width to get it exactly where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Stimulate pulse width, measure arm position, then do a literature search on "system identification".

You *really* want to make sure you're in the linear range of operation, though -- servos have top speeds, and if you hit that top speed in operation, then the servo will no longer behave in a linear manner, and the concept of "transfer function" will go out the window.  At that point you'll either need a full-on nonlinear model (which the manufacturer won't even *know*, any more than they know what a "transfer function" is), or you'll need to characterize the servo with several different input amplitudes and do describing function analysis on the results.

Comment: Arm position would be the degrees (output) of the servo ? And by stimulating pulse width you mean continuously send PWM signals with different duty cycle ?

Comment: That is correct on both counts.

Answer (score 0):

See the Modeling section in this [project](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/MicrocontrollerKit/workflow/BallAndBeamControl.html), to see how a nonlinear model was converted to a linear model, and subsequently used to design and deploy controllers to an Arduino Uno.

It assumes the dynamics of the motor will be fast compared to that of the ball and beam and ignores the former.